# Delegate methods not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols, modalviewcontroller

I'm having some trouble getting a `viewcontroller` to respond to a action inside a `modal` `viewcontroller`.

I have a sidebar with a settings button. This button presents a **settings** `viewcontroller` `modally`, and I want my sidebar to respond when a user taps the **log out** button on my settings `viewcontroller`.

In my `settingsTableViewController.h` I set up the delegate like this:

```
@class SettingsTableViewController;
@protocol SettingsTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)loggedOutUser:(SettingsTableViewController *)viewController;
@end

@interface SettingsTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SettingsTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
....
```

And then in the `settingsTableViewController.m` I synthesize the delegate and call the delegate method like so:

```
@synthesize delegate;
....
- (IBAction)logOut:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate loggedOutUser:self];
    ....
}
```

Furthermore, in my responding `menuTableViewController.h` I set it up like so:

```
@interface MenuTableViewController : UITableViewController <SettingsTableViewControllerDelegate>
```

And then finally I set the delegate in the `prepareForSegue` method in my `menuTableViewController.m`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    ....
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"settingsSegue"]) {
        SettingsTableViewController *stvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        stvc.delegate = self;
    }
    ....
}
```

I simply cannot figure out what's causing this. 
My guess is that the `stvc.delegate = self` doesn't do what it's supposed to, because the `menuTableViewController` responds to the delegate of another `viewcontroller` as well (not modal),  and here I had to set the `delegate = self` in the `viewDidLoad` method, but before the `[self viewDidLoad]` call, as placing it after did not work.

Any help that could resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated! I've been struggling with this for too long now... Thanks!

Comment: If you set a breakpoint inside your prepareForSegue, does your delegate get set?

Comment: Damn, turns out the destination view controller is a navigation controller, and the delegate is therefore not set correctly. I fixed it by writing `((UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController]).viewControllers[0]` instead. 

Why didn't I think about that?!?

Thanks a million!

Comment:  bingo! Because prepareForSegue is a sneaky beast ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my `destinationViewController` is actually a `navigationController`, so the delegate is not set correctly. Thanks to **remus** for telling me to set a breakpoint to check if the delegate was set correctly.

I fixed it by writing

```
SettingsTableViewController *stvc = ((UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController]).viewControllers[0];
```

instead.